# How to use AndroidViewModel inside Fragment. More importantly, Fragments which are generated on the go, through other Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

Android Architechture Compnents recommends to use ViewModel, LiveData, Room, Repository quadology to fetch data from local database.
As [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0) and many other resources described I am following path:

**Database -> Room (Dao) -> Repository -> ViewModel (AndroidViewModel) -> LiveData Observers**

As it says Repository needs to supply application level context to the database and that's why we use AndroidViewModel class to create Repository. AndroidViewModel needs Application object in its constructor.

Now inside Fragments, whenever I use `getActivity().getApplication()` Android Studio warn me that `getActivity()` might return null and `NullPointerException` genrated.

I searched Stackflow and tried `requireActivity().getApplication()`. It worked. Developer said to always use it inside `onActivityCreated()` meathod. I noticed it works fine for only those fragments which are created by Activity. It not works for those Fragments which are created inside another Fragment. They never recive `onActivityCreated()` call.

Now I don't know how I can access AndroidViewModel object from such class. Hope someone understand what is the problem here. Plz help.

Here is the BranchDetailsViewModel class:

```
public class BranchDetailsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    final BranchRepository branchRepository;
    final BankRepository bankRepository;
    final CityRepository cityRepository;
    final DistrictRepository districtRepository;
    final StateRepository stateRepository;

    LiveData<Branch> branch;


    public BranchDetailsViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        branchRepository = new BranchRepository(application);
        bankRepository = new BankRepository(application);
        cityRepository = new CityRepository(application);
        districtRepository = new DistrictRepository(application);
        stateRepository = new StateRepository(application);
    }
}
```

Here is the BranchDetailsFragment which is child to another Fragment. Presently I am passing Application object from the top-level fragment created by Activity to make things work.:

```
public class BranchDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private final Application application;
    private final int branchIid;

    private FragBranchDetailsBinding binding;

    public BranchDetailsFragment(Application application, int branchIid) {
        this.application = application;
        this.branchIid = branchIid;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragBranchDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        BranchDetailsViewModel branchDetailsViewModel = new BranchDetailsViewModel(application);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the application object in the Fragment, you already have it in onViewCreated() method from the passed @NonNull View view which is always not null, so you can do something like that: Application application = (Application)view.getContext().getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 1):

Only Repository needs context to query database. And in fragment we can easily access context. So, instead of creating Repository instance inside View Model, creating Repository instance inside Fragment and then pass it's reference to ViewModel would be safe to avoid memory leak. Here you don't need **Android View Model** because context is no more needed inside View Model.

So, in your case you could pass repository instance from parent fragment to child fragment instead of application instance and use ViewModel instead of AndroidViewModel.

BranchDetailsViewModel may look like :

```
class BranchDetailsViewModel (
 val branchRepository: BranchRepository,
 val bankRepository: BankRepository ,
 val cityRepository: CityRepository,
 val districtRepository: DistrictRepository,
 val stateRepository: StateRepository
) : ViewModel() {
   // Do your stuff using repositories here --------
}
```

Comment: So that means I can't use `AndroidViewModel` class with Fragments as its constructor require Application object and `getActivity().getApplication()` may produce NPE.

Comment: You can use AndroidViewModel, if your requirement is to use context inside ViewModel. Let's say if you are using viewModel as data binding in fragment's UI. But ViewModel should not deal with any UI related stuff.

Comment: Why do not you use dependecy injection ? If you use dependecy injection then only one instance of your repository class will be created as singleton and you just pass its reference throughout your project.